# Django issue uploading files to server

Tags: django, nginx

I believe I have a permission's issue with how my Django instance is set up. The site is up but when I try to upload an image file from the admin it upload and the field has the proper filename but the file isn't uploaded to the server.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name pluscolor.co.ke www.pluscolor.co.ke 138.197.124.71;

    client_max_body_size 32m;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/sammy/revamp/revamp;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/sammy/revamp/revamp;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/sammy/revamp/revamp.sock;
    }
}
```

here's a video that shows the local version and on the server https://youtu.be/loTEmTM67K0 it works only locally.

Comment: Can you show us your view and form?

Comment: I'm doing it from the django admin, the site used to work but I had an issue and changed the permissions to some folders.

Comment: Then all I can suggest, I'm afraid, is to go over the permissions for the relevant user and directories.

Comment: where you hosted your project ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue, I didn't include media_root on the server settings.